# facebook connect - internet explorer 7 & 8 - login issue - blank screen after login - fb_xd_fragment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, authentication, facebooker2

I have an app that uses facebook authentication. A user has no problem logging in when using any modern browser. With ie 7 & 8 the following happens -

The user clicks the login button.
A facebook login window pops up
The user enters their details and clicks submit. 
The pop up remains open and goes to a blank page with this url - 
https://my-app.heroku.com/channel.html?fb_xd_fragment#?=LotsOfRandomUrlParamaters

My code looks like this -

```
<div id="container"  class="facebook_tab" >
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">              
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
          appId  : 'myappid',
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
          oauth  : false,
          channelUrl : 'https://my-app.heroku.com/channel.html'
        });

          var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
</script>
```

It's a rails app using this gem - https://github.com/fionnbharra/facebooker2  - but I don't think that is the cause of the problem.

The rails code used to genertae that login button looks like this -

```
<%= fb_login(:text=>"Log in") do %>
  top.location.href='<%= APP_CONFIG[:my_app_url] %>';
<% end %>
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Facebook SDK problem (all.js). Try searching on fb_xd_fragment in Google. There are multiple solutions, some are a solution, some not...
You may file a bug-report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs